# Need Assistance with Optimizing a LINQ Query with ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm working on an ASP.NET Core MVC application and I need some help optimizing my LINQ queries. Currently my application is running very slowly and I presume it is due to the way I've written my queries. My SQL db contains about 1.9 millions rows of data, with 4 properties for each item.

Here is a a sample of what I have in the controller...

```
model.MostPopular = await _givenNameRepo.GetByAlphaSinceYear(model.StartsWith, model.Gender, model.SortCount, model.SinceYear).ToAsyncEnumerable().ToList();
```

And here is what I have in the repo...

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetByAlphaSinceYear(string alpha, string gender, int sortCount, int sinceYear)
    {
        var names = (from n in _context.AsNoTracking()
                     where n.Name.StartsWith(alpha) && n.Gender == gender && n.Year >= sinceYear
                     group n by new { n.Name } into nn
                     select new
                     {
                         nn.Key.Name,
                         Frequency = nn.Sum(s => s.Frequency)
                     }).OrderByDescending(i => i.Frequency)
                       .Select(j => j.Name).Take(sortCount);

        return names;
    }
```

I was playing around with trying to make the repo flexible, allowing for synchronous or asynchronous operation. But I'm now thinking this may be causing problems given what I have to do in the controller.

One question I guess would be is my query running multiple times given the way I'm calling it? I've read through the LINQ documentation, but it's not sinking into my head regarding when certain deferred operations are executing. As I understand it, the first run would be on the .OrderByDescending, and on that result .Select would run, and on that result .Take would run. But then in the controller, because I'm trying to run asynchronously I think need to call .ToAsyncEnumerable and then .ToList. My gut tells me there is some extra work going on here, but I'm not sure.

EDIT: There is just one table in the db and it looks like this...

```
Id | Year | Name | Gender | Frequency
```

Each year has its own names with their own genders and frequencies. The sample query looks for the most popular names by summing up the frequencies of the names, over some number of years (last year, last 5 years, last 10 years, etc.), and based on gender (names can potentially be male and female), and then sorts them in descending order based on those summed frequencies. Then you take from the top whatever number you want to display to show the most popular names.

Comment: This looks more like an indexing issue on the SQL server side. Do you have an index for these three columns together?

Comment: Without more information its hard to help you. Provide at least a table schema and/or the index set on that table. Searching on non-indexed fields may result in a full or partial table scan

Comment: In addition to the above info - look at which sql query is actually produced by this LINQ one.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies. I'm not familiar with indexing, so let me look into that first and see what I can come up with

Comment: Well Jeff, if you are playing with a table with millions of rows, you better get acquainted with indexing fast my friend... :-)

Comment: Haha. Thanks Juan. I'm reading up on indexing now. I'm new to db stuff, so this is a good learning experience for me. I've got the app running in Azure and I did apply an indexing recommendation per Azure that indexed on Gender and Name. It helped a little, but not much. My queries are still taking upwards of 10 seconds in some cases, which is unacceptable in the web world. In that amount of time, most people could take a nap and then get back to Facebooking.

Comment: Why do you group by name? Shouldn't name be unique?

Comment: What you need is an index that covers all three columns (name, gender and year).

Comment: Why stop there? Why not creste indices for every permutation and combination?!

Comment: Gert, the names are only unique per year and per gender, they aren't unique like say an Id is unique. For example, "Jamie" occurs for both male and female in most years, and in each year, and for each gender, the frequency of occurrence varies. So the name itself is not unique unless you also filter by gender and by year.

Comment: Juan, I've added individual indices for Name, Year, and Gender. So far I've cut the query times by 40%-50%. Not bad, but still would like some improvement. I think the difficulty is that the main queries are doing a lot of calculations based on frequency to rank the names over various periods of time.

Comment: Mardoxx, would you mind elaborating? For example, are you saying have individual indices for Name, Gender, and Year, but also indices for Name/Gender, Name/Year, Gender/Year, etc.? I'm looking into more advanced indexing at the moment. Thanks!

Comment: *names are only unique per year and per gender* Then no doubt you can benefit from a little data normalization. For example, split the data in a names table (unique names) and a table recording year-gender frequencies (with foreign key to name). Doing that, the most expensive part of the query (`Name.StartsWith`) will search in far less records than it does now, probably an order of magnitude less.

Comment: Thanks Gert, I appreciate the feedback.